# Regex to match strings within braces

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to a string that has the following format

**12740(34,12) [abc (a1b2c3) (a2b3c4)......] myId123**

Currently, I have something like this

```
\((?P<expression>\S+)\)
```

But with this, I can capture only the strings within square brackets.

Is there anyway I can capture the integers before the square brackets and also id at the end along with the strings within square brackets.

The number of strings enclosed within small brackets will not be the same. I could also have a string that looks like this

**10(3,2) [abc (a1b2c3)] myId1**

I know that I can write a simple regex for the above expression using brute force. But could anyone please help me write one when the number of strings within the square bracket keeps changing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use a single regex with `re` to capture arbitrary number of groups. You only have as many groups in the match as there are defined in the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ohk, removed..!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is a dupe (whether the OP realizes it or not) of every "parse HTML/XML with regex" question. Do we not have a canonical "Regex/CFG" question to close these with? Maybe we should.

Comment: @JaredSmith: This has nothing to do with HTML/XML parsing. It can be done with a single regex with PyPi `regex` library.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew match arbitrarily nested balanced grouping characters? Or did I misunderstand what the OP wanted?

Comment: @JaredSmith: OP does not need to match nested structures. Anyway, it is possible with PyPi regex, too.

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't believe there is but there's a pop-up saying to check out some other specific things first if your question title includes regex

Comment: I am new in this but `\d+\(\d\d,\d\d\)\s\[\w+\s((\((\w\d)+\))\s)+\]` seems to work in https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the information by using `^` and `$`, which mean start and end respectively:

```
((?P<front>^\d+)|\((?P<expression>\S+)\)|(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$)
```

Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/PoA5k4/1

To make the result more usable, I'd turn it into a dictionary:

```
import re

myStr = "12740(34,12) [abc (a1b2c3) (a2b3c4)......] myId123"
di = {}
for find in re.findall("((?P<front>^\d+)|\((?P<expression>\S+)\)|(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$)",myStr):
    if find[1] != "":
        di["starter"] = find[1]
    elif find[3] != "":
        di["id"] = find[3]
    else:
        di.setdefault("expression",[]).append(find[2])
print(di)
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful. Thanks a lot for your answer.